# CefSharp Javascript async response too fast

Tags: c#, cefsharp

My approach is to visit each link and if all are visited to receive a return value from.
The problem is, when I start the code, I get instantly a response, clearly empty because not all the links are visited.

```
    private async void ibtn_start_visiting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string js = "var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#profiles * .tile__link');document.getElementsByClassName('js-scrollable')[0].scrollBy(0,30);ele.forEach(function(value,index){setTimeout(function(){if(index < ele.length-1){ele[index].click();}else{document.querySelectorAll('.search-results__item').forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));document.getElementsByClassName('js-close-spotlight')[0].click();return 'hallo';}},1000 * index)})";
    
        await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(js).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            var response = x.Result;

            if (response.Success)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    var res = (string)response.Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Response: " + res);
                    
                    
                });
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("NO");
            }
            
        });



    }
```

This is the javascript:

```js
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#profiles * .tile__link');
document.getElementsByClassName('js-scrollable')[0].scrollBy(0,30);
ele.forEach(function(value,index){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(index < ele.length-1){
            ele[index].click();
            
        }
        else{
            
            document.querySelectorAll('.search-results__item').forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
            document.getElementsByClassName('js-close-spotlight')[0].click();
            alert('hallo');
        }
    },1500 * index)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see. Your javascript is using `setTimeout`, which is kind of equivalent to making the function you pass to it also be async. CefSharp doesn't know when those `setTimeout` tasks are completed, hence the early return. The pended javascript code does execute, eventually. To know when that's been completed you've got a couple of options:

1. Make your async javascript code synchronous by getting rid of `setTimeout` completely.
2. Set some global variable in your async javascript code and periodically check your webpage in C# to see if that variable is set.
3. Register some JS handler and call that when your async javascript is completed.

#3 is my favorite, so you might register that handler in C# like so:

```
public class CallbackObjectForJs{
    public void showMessage(string msg){
        // we did it!
    }
}

webView.RegisterJsObject("callbackObj", new CallbackObjectForJs());
```

And your JS might look something like:

```
var totalTasks = 0;
function beginTask() {
  totalTasks++;
}
function completeTask() {
  totalTasks--;
  if (totalTasks === 0) {
    callbackObj("we finished!"); // this function was registered via C#
  }
}

var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#profiles * .tile__link');
document.getElementsByClassName('js-scrollable')[0].scrollBy(0,30);
ele.forEach(function(value,index){
    beginTask();  // NEW
    setTimeout(function(){
        ... // work
        completeTask();
    }, 1500 * index);
})
```

To make this cleaner you may want to look into Javascript's `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Sadly RegisterJsObject got removed and RegisterJsObject and RegisterAsyncJsObject too. And I can't find another solution. You got an idea?

Comment: The features still exist,  you just register an object slightly differently. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript in your case I'd actually use CefSharp.PostMessage see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775#issuecomment-498454221 https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#13-how-do-you-handle-a-javascript-event-in-c